# Invoking methods with parametrized arguments

Tags: java, generics, methods, reflection, event-handling

I'm currently building an event system to handle some events in my application. The EventDispatcher calls methods with parameters, which are assignable from the event's class. This works fine with non-parametrized parameters but i cant find a solution to do this with parametrized arguments (parameters with generic type).
**How can i filter for those too**?

Here is a small excerpt from my Dispacher:

```
private final Event event; // custom Event-class
private final Map<Object, List<Method>> subscriber;

/* snip */

@Override
public void run() {
    subscriber.forEach((sub, methods) -> methods.stream()
            // filter for matching event methods
            .filter(m -> {
                // returns true, even if generic types do not match
                return m.getParameters()[0].getType().isAssignableFrom(event.getClass());
            })
            .forEach(m -> {
                try {
                    m.invoke(sub, event);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("...", e);
                }
            })
    );
}
```

Note: *the given methods in the subscriber map already have the required return type,1 parameter and the Annotation to identify event-methods.*

**EDIT:** From the comments:
The problem is, that Java returns true, when I check for `Event<Integer> isAssignableFrom( Event<String> )`

Comment: and what is the problem? does it compile? if yes, what is runtime exception?

Comment: i want to have this with with parametrized-parameters. So if i have an event method like: https://pastebin.com/DrGDhB3X.

Because Java returns true, when i check for Event<Integer> isAssignableFrom( Event<String>)

Comment: what are parametrized-parameters? how keys and values in `subscriber` are related? what is the type of `event`?

Comment: with parametrized-parameters i mean generic stuff like List<String>

Comment: please describe your initial task. I suspect it can be solved without reflection, with double dispatcher pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and further reading i came up with a test to see if i can match the generics by their [Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html):

```
private static boolean test(Type type1, Type type2) {
    if (type1 == type2) return true;
    if (type1.getTypeName().equals(type2.getTypeName())) {
        if (type1 instanceof ParameterizedType || type2 instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            if (type1 instanceof ParameterizedType && type2 instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                Type[] type1Params = ((ParameterizedType) type1).getActualTypeArguments();
                Type[] type2Params = ((ParameterizedType) type2).getActualTypeArguments();
                if (type1Params.length != type2Params.length) return false;
                for (int i = 0; i < type1Params.length; i++) {
                    if (!test(type1Params[i], type2Params[i])) return false;
                }
                return true; // all generic types in both types are equal pairwise
            }
            return false; // one with generic type and one without
        }
        return true; // both no generic types
    }
    return false; // not equal by name
}
```

**My results:**

- You can match two parameters of methods with this because a [Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) can return a Type[] with [getGenericParameterTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--).
- You cannot check if two instances have the same generic type. Because you get the Type via [getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) only the Type of the Class you have the instance from will be returned without the Generic types.
  *See [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)*